# Blender 3.0 constantly checks on "Depth" option in Orbit & Pan options

Tags: 3d-view, interface, customization, error, settings

This didn't happen before in 2.xx versions. I start a new project or load older project and start working and camera starts jumping around like crazy. I go into option and this nasty option is turned on again. This is a bug? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't do that here although I do usually have it turned on anyway.

Comment: Have you turned it off AND saved preferences? Auto-save does not work for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, only it keeps turning off when I want it to stay on. Every now and then I try to zoom in and find I can't, and then when I check back in preferences I find the setting has changed. Other preferences don't do this, they stay where I set them.